# Match @username and #topic and wrap result in span

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying parse a raw tweet string to match the @username and #topic parts, I'm able to match them but I'm unfamiliar on how to wrap them.

My code:

```
"Hey @someotheruser this is a tweet about #topic1 and #topic1".replace(/(^|)@(\w+)/, '<span class="mention">?result of match?</span>');

"Hey @someotheruser this is a tweet about #topic1 and #topic1".replace(/(^|)#(\w+)/, '<span class="hash">?result of match?</span>');
```

So my question is: How to I get the result of my match, and wrap it with a span?

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: What is that `(^|)` group for? It always matches an empty string.

Comment: I left that out of my answer too; Maybe the OP meant it without grouping; `[^|]` or `^|` so it may act like some kind of escaping-mechanism for normal text @'s and #'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var my_string = 'Hey @someotheruser this is a tweet about #topic1 and #topic1';

my_string = my_string.replace(/(\@\w+)/g, '<span>$&</span>');
my_string = my_string.replace(/(\#\w+)/g, '<span>$&</span>');

console.log(my_string);
```

**Output**

```
Hey <span>@someotheruser</span> this is a tweet about <span>#topic1</span> and <span>#topic1</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

One example:

```
myString.replace(/(^|)@(\w+)/g, function handleMatch(match) {
    return '<span class="mention">' + match + '</span>';
})
.replace(/(^|)#(\w+)/g, function handleMatch(match) {
    return '<span class="hash">' + match + '</span>';
});
```

Comment: Or just do this :) `/(^|)(?:#(\w+))|(?:@(\w+))/g`. **Edit**; I see you've just updated the answer. Guess that's nice too if you want different classes.

Comment: But then you can't differentiate the different span classes ;) __Edit:__ Yeah, tbh, it's a bit clunky compared to the other answers, but an option nonetheless :)

Comment: Was just scribbling on, you can; inside your function :) http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/NGk5v/ So many roads to Rome ^^ Nice thing is with this switch you can even repot an error on a last `else {}` and maybe write an error to the console as the regex mismatched something :)

Comment: True! Although I stand by _clunky_ :P

Comment: Replacement functions seem to be a bit overkill for such a simple task (and are slower)

Comment: Hehe :P Let's overkill it some more with a counter to know which value we are actually finding; http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/NGk5v/4/. You could count the findings per `@` and `#` too if needed ;)